# Pass Values dynamically to String formatter with format specifier

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, slf4j

I am trying to print logs where the params keep changing for every request. I am trying to use String formatter.

Here is my code

MailService.java

```
static final LinkedHashMap<String , String> logMap = new LinkedHashMap<String , String>();

logMap.put("mailType", mailType);
logMap.put("projectId", projectId);

LogUtility.getDownstreamReqLog(LOGGER,jwtTokenProvider,url,logMap);
```

LogUtility.java

```
public static void getDownstreamReqLog(Logger log, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, URI url,LinkedHashMap<String,String> logMap) {

    String message = " {" + BffConstants.REQUEST_ID_KEY + " = %s }" + " {" + BffConstants.REQUEST_URL + " = %s }";

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    String mapKeys = "";
    for (String key : logMap.keySet()) {
        mapKeys = mapKeys + " {" + key + " =%s }";
        values.add(logMap.get(key));
    }

    message = message + mapKeys;

    LogUtility.info(log, message,jwtTokenProvider.getRequestId(),url,values.toArray(new
   String[0]));
}

public static void info(Logger log, String message, Object... args) {
    log.info(getFormattedMessage(message, args));
}

private static String getFormattedMessage(String message, Object... args) {
    String formattedMessage = message;
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        formattedMessage = String.format(message, args);
    }
    return formattedMessage;
}
```

Request Id key and Url is common for all requests. Other params vary based on request.So i am trying to dynamically append key and value pairs to the log info method. Keys are getting passed as expected. But the issue i am facing is values is going as an array.Is there a way where i can pass it as individual Strings as array will cause formatting error. For example Object array args is taking inputs in this format

```
    [0] = "requestId"
    [1] = "url"
    [2] = String[2]
```

I want it to get passed in this format

```
    [0] = "requestId"
    [1] = "url"
    [2] = "value1"
    [3] = "value2"
    and so on... based on number of values present in LinkedHashMap so that respective formatter key gets mapped to respective value.
```

Is there a way i can accomplish it in getDownstreamReqLog method or do i have to start thinking to make changes in getFormattedMessage method itself if its not possible to pass values as individual Strings instead of array? Thank you for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your requestId and url to your values list and call `LogUtility.info` only with your array

```
public static void getDownstreamReqLog(Logger log, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, URI url,LinkedHashMap<String,String> logMap) {

    String message = " {" + BffConstants.REQUEST_ID_KEY + " = %s }" + " {" + BffConstants.REQUEST_URL + " = %s }";

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(jwtTokenProvider.getRequestId()); 
    values.add(url.toString());

    String mapKeys = "";
    for (String key : logMap.keySet()) {
        mapKeys = mapKeys + " {" + key + " =%s }";
        values.add(logMap.get(key));
    }

    message = message + mapKeys;

    LogUtility.info(log, message, values.toArray(new String[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. It worked like a charm. Much appreciated.:) I just didn't focus on other two params much as i kept thinking about dynamic params.